# How to make onTouch works like onTap in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I've implemented an OnTouchListener in my MapActivity and of course I had to override the onTouch() method.

I want it to fire only when I tap on the map - otherwise I can't even move the map.

Here's my onTouch method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

      // SOME ACTIONS ...

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to keep all the dialog stuff you had in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601175 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
```

and:

```
e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
```

if there was and ACTION_UP event after and ACTION_DOWN, and no ACTION_MOVE between, its a tap

UPDATED:

```
private int mLastMotionEventAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {


      // SOME DOWN ACTIONS ...

    } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

      // SOME MOVE ACTIONS ...

    } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
       if (mLastMotionEventAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

         // SOME TAP ACTIONS ...

       }
    }
    mLastMotionEventAction = e.getAction();
    return true;
}
```

Another option (for sensitive devices):

```
    private long mLastDownEventTime = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           mLastDownEventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

          // SOME DOWN ACTIONS ...

        } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

          // SOME MOVE ACTIONS ...

        } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           if (System.currentTimeMillis() - mLastDownEventTime < 500){

             // SOME TAP ACTIONS ...

           }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

This will trigger tap action only if 200ms or less have passed since last down press. Of course, you can change the timing for best UX.

Comment: mmm, allright - but how can I check the order of fired events?

Comment: use a global int to save the last action that occured

Comment: There is no easier and more efficient way?

Comment: is mLastMotionEventAction not equal to MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN after event MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is triggered?

Comment: maybe you can try the above timing approach

Comment: Timing approach works better - but I can't move the map : ) tapping works great, b ut I can't do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You must return `false` if you want to pass the event along to the Map as well. Otherwise, as you describe, the map will not react to touch gestures. This is because, returning `true` means that you *consumed* the event.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but the right way to do it is using `getScaledTouchSlop()` which returns the distance in pixels a touch can wander before we think the user is scrolling.

Implement it like this in your onTouch method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int mSwipeSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).
                    getScaledTouchSlop();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // DO
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            // DO
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                float x = event.getX() + v.getTranslationX();
                float deltaX = x - mDownX;
                float deltaXAbs = Math.abs(deltaX);
                float y = event.getY() + v.getTranslationY();
                float deltaY = Y - mDownY;
                float deltaYAbs = Math.abs(deltaY);
                float absDist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(deltaXAbs, 2) + Math.pow(deltaXAbs, 2));
                if (!mSwiping) {
                    if (absDist > mSwipeSlop) {
                        mSwiping = true;
                    }
                }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                if (mSwiping) {
                    // DO MOVE ACTIONS
                }
                else {
               // DO TAP ACTIONS
                }
            }
            break;
        default: 
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
```

developer page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#getScaledTouchSlop()